# Project Euler #19 - 2 less

Tags: java, algorithm, date

I would like to ask someone if he/she can help me find the bug where I lose 2 solutions in this problem. My code isn't very pretty and readable but I think it is simple enough to understand logic here. I am sitting on this one for hour and even made up different solution which works but can't find problem in this one.

```
private static int _year = 1900;
private static int[] _months = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
private static int _month = 0;
private static int _day = 7; //we start from Sunday
private  static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(_year !=1901) 
        nextSunday(_day, _month, _year);

    while(true) {
        if(_year == 2000 && _month == 11 && _day > 31) break;
        nextSunday(_day, _month, _year);
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}

private static void nextSunday(int day, int month, int year) {
    if(isSundayFirst(_day)) counter++;

    if(year == 2000 && month == 11 && day + 7 > _months[month]) { //to break loop
        _day = day + 7;
    } else if(month == 11 && day + 7 > _months[month]) { // new year, end of month
        _day = day + 7 - _months[month];
        _month = 0;
        _year++;
    } else if(month == 1 && isLeapYear(year) && day + 7 > 29) { // leap year end of february
        _day = day + 7 - 29;
        _month++;
    } else if(month == 1 && !isLeapYear(year) && day + 7 > _months[month]) { // not leap year end of february
        _day = day + 7 - _months[month];
        _month++;
    } else if(day + 7 > _months[month]) { // end of month
        _day = day + 7 - _months[month];
        _month++;
    } else { // next in same month
        _day = day + 7;
    }
}

private static boolean isSundayFirst(int day) {
    return day == 1;
}

private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if(isCentury(year)) {
        if(year % 400 == 0) return true;
    } else {
        return year % 4 == 0;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isCentury(int year) {
    return year % 100 == 0;
}
```

I got 169 such Sundays. I should get 2 more.

Here is the problem:

> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some
>   research for yourself.
>
> ```
> 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> Thirty days has September,
> April, June and November.
> All the rest have thirty-one,
> Saving February alone,
> Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
> And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
> ```
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth
>   century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

I will appreciate any effort. Thank you.

PS I know this `_name` style isn't Java like but I was writing it fast without intention of posting it anywhere tbh.

Comment: Use [this list](https://ethercalc.org/9zzyzjr6omc9) to find out which ones you are missing

Comment: First, this cannot be run as-is; please add a class wrapper; a visual inspection doesn't show me anything untoward. Next, I'd ask if as you loop you print out the first Sunday of each year, do they match up with the calendar? If you are skipping a leap year day, for instance, this might be somewhere to look.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that your spec says `1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000`, but your code starts from `_year = 1900`, but that would only increase the count, assuming the rest of the code was correct..

Comment: I was moving counter method inside iterate method and forgot about this first loop which is just shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code, one that causes you to over count by 2 and another that causes you to undercount by 4.

1. **Issue #1** The problem to tells you to start counting in 1901, but you start counting in 1900.

   Change

   ```
   if(isSundayFirst(_day)) counter++;
   ```

   to

   ```
   if(isSundayFirst(_day) && _year >= 1901) counter++;
   ```

   to fix this.
2. **Issue #2** The issue lies in this condition:

   ```
   else if(day + 7 > _months[month]) { // end of month
       _day = day + 7 - _months[month];
       _month++;
   }
   ```

   You've handled the case where it is February in the previous two conditions, so you need to check to make sure it is not February here. Changing the condition to

   ```
   else if(month != 1 && day + 7 > _months[month])
   ```

   will fix your issue.

**Sidenote:** The structure of your nextSunday method made it quite difficult to decipher, so here is my effort to simplify it (you will now break when `_year > 2000`):

```
private static void nextSunday(int day, int month, int year) {
    int febNum = isLeapYear(_year) ? 29 : 28;
    int dayCount = (month == 1) ? febNum : _months[_month]; //days in current month

    _day += 7;

    if (_day > dayCount) {  //new month
        _month++;
        _day -= dayCount;
    } 
    if (_month == 12) {    //new year
        _month = 0;
        _year++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Issue#1 is silly. I explained it in comment above. First I thought it is problem of counter placement cause I was getting 167! But this Issue#2... That was the problem. Thanks for clarification and advices.